# Magento 1.9.3.8 insert fields in one step checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, php, checkout

I have magento 1.9.3.8. I use amasty customer attributes and one step checkout. In out theme's folder I have added layout files for these attributes and a new customer attributes phtml file with this code:

```
<?php
/**
* @author Amasty Team
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2008-2012 Amasty (http://www.amasty.com)
* @package Amasty_Customerattr
*/ 

/* @var $this Amasty_Customerattr_Block_Customer_Fields */
$relations = $this->getElementsRelation();

/*
 * Get form elements to be rendered
 */
$formElements = $this->getFormElements();

$jsCode = Mage::getModel('amcustomerattr/validation')->getJS();
?>

<?php if ($this->isShowHeader()): ?>
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class=""><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
        <div style="float: left;">
            <ul class="form-list">
            <?php foreach ($formElements as $element): ?>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <?php echo $element->toHtml(); ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
<!-- CUSTOM IMAGE AT THE RIGHT: <div style="float: right;"><img src="PATH HERE" /></div>-->
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
<?php if ($this->isShowHeader()): ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>

<?php if (!Mage::registry('amcustomerattr_client_side')):?>
    <style>
        #amcustomerattr .required {
            color: #EB340A;
        }

        .amcustomerattr .required {
            color: #EB340A;
        }

        #amcustomerattr .hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        .amcustomerattr .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript">

<?php echo $jsCode; ?>

Validation.addAllThese([
    ['validate-tendigits', 'Please use 10 digit numbers only in this field. Please avoid spaces or other characters such as dots or commas.', function(v) {
        return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) ||  /^(\d){10}$/.test(v);
    }],

    ['validate-aaa-0000', 'Please use the value in the following format: AAA-0000', function(v) {
        return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) ||  /^([A-Za-z]){3}-(\d){4}$/.test(v);
    }],

    ['validate-checkboxgroup-required', 'Please select an option.', function(v, elm) {
        id = elm.id.substr(0, elm.id.search('___'));
        checkboxGroupChecked = false;
        $$('input[id^=' + id + ']').each(function(checkbox){
            if (checkbox.checked)
            {
                checkboxGroupChecked = true;
            }
        });
        return checkboxGroupChecked;
    }],

    ['validate-radiogroup-required', 'Please select an option.', function(v, elm) {
        id = elm.id.substr(0, elm.id.search('___'));
        radioGroupChecked = false;
        $$('input[id^=' + id + ']').each(function(radio) {
            if (radio.checked) {
                radioGroupChecked = true;
            }
        });
        return radioGroupChecked
    }],
]);

/* Relations table */
var amcustomerattr_relations = '<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($relations->toArray());?>'.evalJSON();
var indexed_elements = [];

/*
 * Hide element and its label
 */
function amcustomerattr_hide_element(id) 
{
    if ($(id)) {
        if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.") == -1) {
            if ($(id).readAttribute('class') == 'field-row') {
                $(id).hide();
            } else {
                $(id).parentNode.hide();
            }
        }
        else{
            $(id).hide();
            classAttr = 'label[for='+id+']';
            $$(classAttr).each(function(el) {
                el.hide();
            });
        }
    }
    hide_all_childs(id);
}

/*
 * Show element and its label
 */
function amcustomerattr_show_element(id) 
{
    if ($(id)) {
        if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.") == -1) {
            if ($(id).readAttribute('class') == 'field-row') {
                $(id).show();
            } else {
                $(id).parentNode.show();
            }
        } else {
            $(id).show();
            classAttr = 'label[for='+id+']';
            $$(classAttr).each(function(el) {
                el.show();
            });
        }

        var options = amcustomerattr_find_elements(id);
        if (options) {
            if ($(id).readAttribute('class') == ' select') {
                element = $(id);
                amcustomerattr_manage_dep(element);
            } else {
                options.each(function(item) {
                    element = $(id+'___'+item.value);
                    amcustomerattr_manage_dep(element);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Hide childs elements and them labels
 */
function hide_all_childs(id)
{
    // Find dependents elements
    var dep = amcustomerattr_find_elements(id);

    // Iterate throw elements and show required elements
    dep.each(function(el) {
        amcustomerattr_hide_element(el.code);
    });

}

/*
 * Manage dependencies.
 * Hide or show dependent attribute
 */
function amcustomerattr_manage_dep(element)
{
    if (element) {
        var elementId = element.id;

        if (element.id.indexOf('___') > 0) {
            elementId = element.id.substr(0, element.id.search('___')); 
        }

        if (element.readAttribute('rel')) {
            elementId = element.readAttribute('rel');
        }

        // Find dependents elements
        var dep = amcustomerattr_find_elements(elementId);

        if (element.type == 'radio') {
            hide_all_childs(elementId);
        }

        // Iterate throw elements and show required elements
        dep.each(function(el) {
            if ($(el.code)) {
                // Checkboxes and radio
                if (element.checked == false) {
                    if (must_hide(elementId, dep)) {
                        amcustomerattr_hide_element(el.code);
                    }
                } else if (element.checked) {
                    if (element.getValue().indexOf(el.value) >= 0) {
                        amcustomerattr_show_element(el.code);
                        indexed_elements.push(el.code);
                    } else if (indexed_elements.indexOf(el.code) < 0) {
                        if (must_hide(elementId, dep)) {
                            amcustomerattr_hide_element(el.code);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Multiselect and select
                    if (element.getValue().indexOf(el.value) >= 0) {
                        amcustomerattr_show_element(el.code);
                        indexed_elements.push(el.code);
                    } else if (indexed_elements.indexOf(el.code) < 0) {
                        amcustomerattr_hide_element(el.code);
                    }
                }

            } 
        });
        indexed_elements = [];
    }
}

function must_hide(elementId, dep)
{
    var hide = true;
    dep.each(function(el) {
        element = $(elementId+'___'+el.value);
        if (element.checked == true) {
            hide = false;
        }
    });
    return hide;
}

/*
 * Listen elements
 */
function amcustomerattr_listen_element(id) {
    if ($(id)) {
        $(id).observe('change', function(event) {
            var element = Event.element(event);
            amcustomerattr_manage_dep(element);
        });
    }
}

/*
 * Get dependents element for elementId
 */
function amcustomerattr_find_elements(elementId)
{
    var elements = [];
    amcustomerattr_relations.items.each(function(item) {
        if (item.parent_code == elementId) {
            var el = {
                'code' : item.dependent_code,
                'value' : item.option_id
            };
            elements.push(el);
        }
    });
    return elements;
}

var shownElements = [];

<?php 
/*
 * Hide dependent elements
 * Listen for changes
 */
foreach($relations as $relation) { ?>
    var parent = $('<?php echo $relation->getParentCode() ?>');     
    if (parent) {
        if (parent.value == '<?php echo $relation->getOptionId()?>') {
            amcustomerattr_show_element('<?php echo $relation->getDependentCode() ?>');
            shownElements.push('<?php echo $relation->getDependentCode() ?>');
        }
    } 

    var parent = $('<?php echo $relation->getParentCode() ?>___<?php echo $relation->getOptionId()?>');     
    if (parent) {
        if (parent.value == '<?php echo $relation->getOptionId()?>' && parent.readAttribute('checked') == 'checked') {
            amcustomerattr_show_element('<?php echo $relation->getDependentCode() ?>');
            shownElements.push('<?php echo $relation->getDependentCode() ?>');
        }
    }

    if (shownElements.indexOf('<?php echo $relation->getDependentCode() ?>') < 0) {
        amcustomerattr_hide_element('<?php echo $relation->getDependentCode() ?>');
    }

    amcustomerattr_listen_element('<?php echo $relation->getParentCode() ?>___<?php echo $relation->getOptionId()?>');
    amcustomerattr_listen_element('<?php echo $relation->getParentCode() ?>');
<?php
} 
?> 
</script>

<!--[if IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $$('.amcustomerattr').each(function(el) {
        el.style.position='relative';
        el.style.left='-150px';
    });  
</script>
<![endif]-->

<?php         
Mage::register('amcustomerattr_client_side', 'displayed'); 
endif; // End Script output?>
```

This give a  in checkout page but it is always hidden as I inspect the page:

```
<fieldset id="amcustomerattr26" class="amcustomerattr" style="
display: none;">
```

What am I doing wrong? I am stucked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution.The problem wasn't on attributes.phtml file. There was another file called relations.phtml

It had in its code a lot of these:

`$(id).parentNode.parentNode`

This changed in every place with:

```
$(id).parentNode
```

This changed dom and we are fine now in checkout.